How to use Finite Decimal Continuity to Define Real Number Arithmetic?
Here is some context for my question: In "Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms" by Hubbard & Hubbard, in Appendix A.1 on real number arithmetic they construct what we mean by real number arithmetic from arithmetic on the set of finite decimals $\mathbb{D}$. A finite decimal is obtained by a k-truncation of an infinite decimal $a = \dots 000a_na_{n-1}\dots a_1.a_{-1}a_{-2}000\dots$ where every digit after the the position of the digit corresponding to $10^k$ (where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) is turned into a $0$: $\lbrack a \rbrack_k = \dots 000a_n \dots a_k000 \dots$.
A mapping $f: \mathbb{D}^{n} \to \mathbb{D}$ is considered $\mathbb{D}$-continuous  (or "finite decimal continuous") if, for all integers $N$ and $k$, there exists an integer $l$ such that if $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ are two elements of $\mathbb{D}^n$ with all $|x_i|, |y_i| < N$, and if $|x_i - y_i| < 10^{-l}$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$, then
$$|f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) - f(y_1, \ldots, y_n)| < 10^{-k} \tag{A1.4}$$ we also have the definition that two points $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are k-close if $|\lbrack x_{i}\rbrack_{-k} - \lbrack y_{i}\rbrack_{-k}| \leq 10^{-k}$ for each $i=1, \dots, n$.
Here's the part I have trouble with:

if $f: \mathbb{D}^{n} \to \mathbb{D}$ is  $\mathbb{D}$-continuous, then define $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by the formula $$\tilde{f}(\textbf{x}) = \sup_k \inf_{l\leq -k}f(\lbrack x_1 \rbrack_l, \dots, \lbrack x_n \rbrack_l). \tag{A1.5}$$ Proposition A1.6. The function $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is the unique function that coincides with $f$ on $\mathbb{D}^n$ and satisfies the continuity condition that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that when $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are l-close and all coordinates $x_i$ of $\textbf{x}$ satisfy $|x_i| < N$, then $\tilde{f}(\textbf{x})$ and $\tilde{f}(\textbf{y})$ are k-close.

To prove this, the textbook suggests you first check that $\sup_k \inf_{l\geq k}f(\lbrack x_1 \rbrack_l, \dots, \lbrack x_n \rbrack_l)$ is well-defined, i.e. that the sets of numbers involved are bounded (presumably instead of $\inf_{l\geq k}$ they meant $\inf_{l\leq -k}$ as they had in A1.5 and this is a typo although it's not in the errata). They also ask you why the sup and inf are there. I'm not sure how to prove this and I don't even know what k corresponds to here as it isn't defined. How can we show that these infima exist? What is the purpose of taking the supremum of the infimum here? Apparently it's all related to defining arithmetic operations on the reals. So, addition, for example $x + y = \tilde{A}(x, y)$. The point being to extend these ideas to infinite decimals.
